# jQuery Mobile loop not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loops, mobile

Here is [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ddB3/) of the problem.

Clicking on "Lizard" should [show a picture of a lizard](http://jsfiddle.net/axr7k/) in both cases.

When replacing the `"+ entries[index] +"` with 1 and 6 respectively, everything works fine. When doing it with a loop, it does not work anymore.

I have no idea why.

Comment: An immediate fix: http://jsfiddle.net/7KnZd/1/ . By the time the event handlers are executed (when a `click` event occurs), the loop has completed...meaning that `index` refers to the last item in the loop, so `entries[index]` inside the handlers won't refer to what you expect. My example captures the value of `index` by creating a new scope (calling `handleItem`) so that all references to `index` inside the handlers will be the specific point in the loop

Comment: @Ian Thanks! I would have spent ages figuring that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is that you expect `entries[i]` to have a vaule inside the `click`event.

```
$("#"+ entries[1] +"-choice-C").bind("click", function() {
    $("#"+ entries[1] +"-lizard").show();
});
```

The value of `entries[i]` when you click will be *undefined*, because the value if `i` will be 2 (the same as the length of the array).

What you need is a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341500/what-difficulty-exactly-closure-resolved-in-javascript/17341849#17341849) to keep the value of `i`, and here is an example:

```
var items = ["a","b", "c"];
var displayItem = function (i) {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        alert(items[i]);
    }, 100);
}

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    displayItem(i);
}
```

For the code that soves your problem, got to the [feedle](http://jsfiddle.net/7KnZd/1/) that @Ian commented.